# Make an http request through C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpcontext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

Hi

I am wondering is it possible to have in you C# code(through a scheduler that is on it's own thread and has no knowledge of httpcontext) a request that goes to a controller ?

```
//server side code
// do calculations 
// post to a controller that takes in a list of view models
// do stuff with the collection of view models.

public myControllerIwantToCallFromServerSide(List<VM> viewModels)
{
   // stuff here
}
```

I need some way to do an http request so that I can get a httpcontext as I need to a live http context to use a library(action mailer) that takes an mvc view and renders it into a email and sends it.

Comment: It's certainly possible, it just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @R0MANARMY - Ya I know it does not seem ideal but I am looking at few choices do something like that or I have to make my own smtp email sender and have to try to make these email sent look the same as the one from this library expect I lose the mvc views and master pages or rip out all my emails I made so far with the library and start all over. So unless someone can tell me something better I am choosing what seems to be the best out of the worst cases.

Comment: @Richard - I believe what you posted needs a live http context what I don't have.

Comment: You keep repeating that you don't have an http context, but if you're inside an action you can get a hold of it.  Are you not doing this from an ASP.NET action?

Comment: @R0MANARMY - No i don't have a live http context. I am starting a quartz scheduler through application start that runs in it's own thread and does not make a http context.

Comment: You may want to include that information in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "prop1", "value 1" },
        { "prop1", "value 2" },
    };
    var result = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/", values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the method Richard posted. I call the viewengine to render my partial view, then I use `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` to generate the email and send it off.

I apologize, as I would preferrably comment above, but I do not have the reputation to do so.

Comment: I think you need a http context to use that. If that worked then I could use the library I am using since that's pretty much what it is doing. It takes a view renders it and sends it off.